# В обычной форме всё работает, а после компиляции не работает все код

Tags: python, opencv

Пробовал компилировать при помощью py2exe, nuitka и pyinstaller, ни один не помог.
Код:

```
        while (True):
            screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(761, 536, 1158, 548)))
            image = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=2.55, fy=3, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
            image = 255 - thresh
            freeze_support()
            pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
            config = '--psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABC012'
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang="eng", config=config)
            print(text)
            pyautogui.typewrite(text, interval=0)
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            pyautogui.doubleClick()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Опишите конкретно - ошибку выкидывает, ничего не происходит, висит, что?

Comment: Ничего не происходит(pyinstaller,nuitka), вылетает cmd(py2exe)